# jQuery and knockout playing bad together

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Consider this

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li class="popupClick" data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popupClick').click(function() {
        alert('Show popup');
    });
});
```

When the page loads, clicking the `li` shows the alert. But if the observableArray `items` is changed and new `li`-nodes are appended to the node, we can't click 'em.

We would need to re-run the javascript code above every time `items` is changed? Some nice way of doing that?

I do not want to use the `data-bind="click: ..."` event here since this click is not really part of the ViewModel and we have lots of legacy jQuery stuff that registers click-handlers like this for popups, tooltips, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the knockout `click` binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to update your jQuery code to use the `on()` method. The documentation can be found here http://api.jquery.com/on/

So it would be;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.popupClick', function() {
        alert('Show popup');
    });
});
```

You will need to do this because in your code, the elements do not exist when you are assigning the click event.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to

To take it further, you could give your wrapping `<ul>` an ID or class name, then attach the `on()` method to this. e.g.

Updated HTML

```
<ul id="myItems" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li class="popupClick" data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

Updates JS

```
$('#myItems').on('click', '.popupClick', function(){
    alert("Show popup");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Any comments on performance hits for using document as the container for the delegated events instead of the ul-element?

Comment: There are many blog posts on the net with performance counters, whether they are accurate or outdated I do not know. It is suggested that binding to the closests static element is the fastest. This way it is not searching the whole DOM for the element, only the closes static element.

Answer (score 3):

For new added elements you'll need to use delegated event handlers

```
$(document).on('click','.popupClick', function() {
    alert('Show popup');
});
```

Take a look to [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) official documentation for more details

Comment: Only issue I have with this is that it forces a scan of the whole DOM. Something the OP should keep in mind that it would be better if they can narrow down that selector to something closer to the context, or the whole DOM tree is watched for click events, if I understand how it works correctly. Obviously, as we don't know what the rest of the OP's code looks like, we can't say /where/ to put that selector, but the closer to the target element in the DOM tree, the better. Unless I'm completely off base, here, and I'd be happy to be corrected, as it'll simplify my own code a lot! :)

Comment: @mori57: agreed about using the closer parent as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using the jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for binding events to dynamically generated objects.